# Названия нот

Tags: этимология

В сети попалась интересная информация о названиях нот:
Do – Dominus – Господь;
Re – rerum – материя;
Mi – miraculum – чудо;
Fa – familias рlanetarium – семья планет, т.е. солнечная система;
Sol – solis – Солнце;
La – lactea via – Млечный путь;
Si – siderae – небеса.

Правда ли это? И тогда почему систем названия нот две (есть еще: C,D,E,F и т.д.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почему ж не названия? Это обозначения нот на письме:

Каждая октава содержит 7 нот: до, ре, ми, фа, соль, ля, си. Для записи нот часто используют их условные буквенные обозначения. В разных странах/системах эти обозначения различны, поэтому всегда желательно согласовывать используемую систему обозначений.
http://balalaika.org.ru/pitch-names.htm

http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anderssprachige_Tonbezeichnungen

Об истории названий интересно здесь:

http://muzicforchildren.blogspot.ru/2010/11/blog-post_04.html

Конечно, цель-мнемотехника, но ведь названия так и закрепились. Почему ж это неправильно?

Answer (score 0):

Это не названия. Это слова для их быстрого запоминания.

И нет никаких систем названия. До, ре, ми - это звук, по которому часто называют ноту. А правильное их название - заглавными латинскими буквами.